# What are binary operators in haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-operators

So I wanted to understand the functions `foldl` and `foldr` in [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldl)
they say that these functions apply to binary operators. But I don't get what these *binary operators* are. I know that `(+)` and `(-)` are binary operators but what defines them ?

Comment: In Haskell a binary function is a function which doesn't deal with functors, aplicative functors, monadic values etc as arguments or returned values. In another words just simple functions are binary functions.

Comment: @Redu That's not what a [binary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) is. I'm not sure I know of a term for what you're describing, actually ("first-order function" *almost* comes close "in spirit," but they can involve functors, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually mathematicians define a *binary operator* is a function that takes two arguments. In some papers it is a requirement that the arguments and the result are defined over the same set.

The fact that the function `?` takes two arguments results in the fact that mathematicians frequently use infix notation (like `x ? y`). For instance `(+)`, `(*)`, etc. are clearly binary operators.

Comment: Oh so that _binary_ stands for the operator is taking  _two_  elements.. well that should be obvious to me. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the term usually implies that both operands are from the same set. Like, I'd imagine most people consider division to be a binary operator even though it's type is `R * R \ {0} -> R`, not `R * R -> R`. And in the specific context of the `fold` functions, "binary operator" definitely does not imply that the operand types must be the same, as that is not the case.

Comment: Yes you are right but the word _binary_ is kind of a hint for that.

Comment: @sepp2k surely the division operator is partial with type `R * R -> R`?

Comment: `(:)` is an obvious example of a binary operator whose two arguments are not of the same type.

Comment: @GarethR I think sepp2k is saying that it *is* partial if you try to give it the type `R * R -> R`, but it is total if you take its type as `R * (R \ {0}) -> R` (and using that example because `R` and `R \ {0}` are not the same).

Comment: @DavidYoung I'm not disagreeing with the main point that division would be an operator even if its two arguments had different types.

Comment: @DavidYoung I'm merely saying `R * R \ {0} -> R` isn't the conventional type of the division operator. After all, if division wasn't a partial function, physicists wouldn't have problems with singularities in black holes... but it is and they do.